# Hiding Empty Strings On Google Maps Info Window

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps to plot a number of pins and am having problems hiding empty strings within the info window.

All locations have a name and address but then there are 3 fields which will not necessarily all have a value.

These are:

- telephone number
- email address
- website

  ```
  var markersOnMap = [{
     title: "Location One",
     placeName: "Location One",
     address: "Address",
     telephone: "01234567890",
     website: "http://somewebaddress.com",
     emailaddress: "",
     LatLng: [{
        lat: 40.4319077,
        lng: 116.5703749
     }]
  }];
  ```

I then put the information into a variable to output it.

```
    var contentString = '<div id="content"><p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName + '</p><p>' + markersOnMap[i].address + '</p><p>T: ' + markersOnMap[i].telephone + '</p><p><a href="' + markersOnMap[i].website + '" target="_blank">' + markersOnMap[i].website + '</a></p><p><a href=mailto:"' + markersOnMap[i].emailaddress + '>' + markersOnMap[i].emailaddress + '</a></p></div>';
```

In the example above, Location One, I would like to hide the email address as it does not have a value.

How do I check if the value of those strings are empty and then not output them on a per location basis.

If anyone can provide any assistance, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use proper var and ternary operator (or if ) for check each content and set the proper html dinamic string code

```
aPlaceName = (markersOnMap[i].placeName !='' ? '<p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName + '</p>' :'');
aAddress = (markersOnMap[i].address !='' ? '<p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName + '</p>' :'');7
 ...
```

and build the contentString using the var

```
 var contentString = '<div id="content">' + aPlaceName + aAddress..... +'</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to build the `contentString` incrementally if the pieces exist:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'
if (!!markersOnMap[i].placeName)
  contentString += '<p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName + '</p>';
if (!!markersOnMap[i].address)
  contentString += '<p>' + markersOnMap[i].address + '</p>';
if (!!markersOnMap[i].telephone)
  contentString += '<p>T: ' + markersOnMap[i].telephone + '</p>';
if (!!markersOnMap[i].website) 
  contentString += '<p><a href="' + markersOnMap[i].website + '" target="_blank">' + markersOnMap[i].website + '</a></p>';
if (!!markersOnMap[i].emailaddress)
  contentString += '<p><a href=mailto:"' + markersOnMap[i].emailaddress + '>' + markersOnMap[i].emailaddress + '</a></p>';
contentString += '</div>';
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3fkngt5b/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
var markersOnMap = [{
    title: "Location One",
    placeName: "Location One",
    address: "Address",
    telephone: "01234567890",
    website: "http://somewebaddress.com",
    emailaddress: "",
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 40.4319077,
      lng: 116.5703749
    }]
  },
  {
    title: "Location Two",
    placeName: "Location Two",
    address: "Address2",
    emailaddress: "",
    LatLng: [{
      lat: 40.432,
      lng: 116.58
    }]
  }
];

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    marker.addListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function(evt) {
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'

        if (!!markersOnMap[i].placeName)

          contentString += '<p>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName + '</p>';

        if (!!markersOnMap[i].address)

          contentString += '<p>' + markersOnMap[i].address + '</p>';

        if (!!markersOnMap[i].telephone)

          contentString += '<p>T: ' + markersOnMap[i].telephone + '</p>';

        if (!!markersOnMap[i].website)

          contentString += '<p><a href="' + markersOnMap[i].website + '" target="_blank">' + markersOnMap[i].website + '</a></p>';

        if (!!markersOnMap[i].emailaddress)

          contentString += '<p><a href=mailto:"' + markersOnMap[i].emailaddress + '>' + markersOnMap[i].emailaddress + '</a></p>';

        contentString += '</div>';
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
      }
    })(i))
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
    '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
    'Heritage Site.</p>' +
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
    '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much taking the time to post a detailed answer.  Works great too!!!